# Pandas python XLS group by ID

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a .xls file which has many rows. The IDs in some of the rows are repeated, and I would like to group the repeated rows' data by saving the **date**, **name**, **surname**, and **email** from the first row and combining **serial numbers** and **quantity** from other rows into a list, dictionary, or some other format that would be readable, or just a new .xls/.xlsm file with those values as new columns in the same row.

Example Data:

| ID | Date | Name | Surname | Email | Serial | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-05-01 | Alice | Wonderland | Alice@gmail.com | 12345678324 | 5 |
| 1 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | 322i3242344 | 4 |
| 1 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | 43234333344 | 2 |
| 2 | 2021-06-01 | Sherlock | Holmes | Mystery@gmail.com | 93293928492 | 1 |
| 2 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | 41114333344 | 5 |

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Some inquiries for your posted question: 

Please provide a 
[minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), or anything that shows you put the [required minimum of research effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/7318488) into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `ffill` before `groupby`

```
df.ffill().groupby(['ID','Date','Name','Surname','Email']).agg(list).reset_index()
Out[15]: 
   ID        Date  ...                                   Serial   Quantity
0   1  2021-05-01  ...  [12345678324, 322i3242344, 43234333344]  [5, 4, 2]
1   2  2021-06-01  ...               [93293928492, 41114333344]     [1, 5]
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, sorry for a question this simple